# extends base.html error

Tags: django-templates

Hello and thank you in advance...

In Django I have a child template that updates a base.html template.  I keep getting an error:

`<ExtendsNode: extends "base.html"> must be the first tag in the template.`

When the code in the child template looks like this:

```
{% extends "simple/base.html" %}

{% block picklist %}

        <title></title>

        <h1>Simple Index</h1> #...
```

I dont get why I am getting this error, when the EXTENDS tag is clearly the first tag.

Both the base and the child template live in the same directory, in my template path /simple.

Thank you,

dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out...

I had another `{% extends %}` tag on the templet which was commented out using HTML `<!--  -->` comments.  The comments were ignored and the extends tag was read and generated the 503 error.

Thank you,

dp